# what is java installation structure in linux?

Tags: java, linux

When i run command **which java** getting output **/usr/bin/java**

when i run **ll /usr/bin/java** getting output **/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java**

In /usr/lib/ i found following folders with 4kb size what are these folders ?

```
java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64
jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
jre-1.5.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.5.0
jre-1.5.0-gcj -> java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre
jre-1.7.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre
jre-gcj -> /etc/alternatives/jre_gcj
jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
```

In /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin i found java is that java file ?
When i want to set java_home which path should i use ?
What is excatly difference netweem jdk and these jvm folders?

Comment: Can you check if `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`? I guess II mean the usual `ls -l`?

Comment: yes that is symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/ and /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/ is symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/ as you can see in question ...so what are all these ..why i can't have simple /home/jdk1.7/bin folder so i can set java_home easily ..

Comment: Why do you need a specific java home folder anyway?

Comment: @Eypros some tools depend on correctly set `$JAVA_HOME`, e.g. maven, gradle, ant.

Comment: I don't think I needed $JAVA_HOME to install maven. I used eclipse for that though (m2e I think). Can't you done something similar?

Comment: @Eypros if you cloudera , hortonworks or hadoop for these tools you need to set java_home ..so we need specific jdk folder where we can set java_home not all these garbage files ...

Comment: @Eypros you only need to setup `$JAVA_HOME` when using java from the command line. Installing a JDK into eclipse is the eclipse equivalent to setting the JAVA_HOME var.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK contains other tools, like JavaDoc, JavaDB, Javac, ..., while the JRE only those that are needed to run Java programs (I think that is the JRE).

Linux systems support multiple installed Java versions, you can switch between them using the `update-alternatives` program. I would not recommend the gcj version of the Java distributions, you probably will have the least problems with the Sun (Oracle) Java versions.

Comment: so when i want set to java_home in hadoop or some other tool which package should i use these jre or download separate JDK 1.7

Comment: @sandy_ws: That depends on what you want to achieve. If you set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jre-1.7.0`, then you can switch the Java version used by using `update-alternatives`. If you want to use a specific version, it might make more sense to set `JAVA_HOME` to a specific Java version. That will break when you install a new version of Java, though. The packaging system will tell `update-alternatives` about new versions but it won't try to figure out all places where you set `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Usually the JDK is a safe bet. For example if the program you want to use the `tools.jar` (for example scripting), it is better to use JDK. If it works with the JRE only it does not matter too much which you choose.